# Docker top result in no such container

Tags: mongodb, docker

After this steps:

1. `docker run --name mymongo -d mongo`
2. `docker container ps`
3. `docker top mongo`

I'm getting an error of:

> Error response from daemon: No such container: mongo

Inside the `docker container ps` I can see the Image mongo, any suggestion why the `docker top mongo` does not show the mongo container?

[image]

*docker container on windows 10 home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the container name is `mymongo` , so the command is :

```
docker top mymongo
```

or you can also use the `Container ID`